# How do i add data before a specific line in a file

Tags: java

i would like to know how can i add some data before a given line in a file , eg. like in the image i would like to add something before  the Condition1 tag but can't manage to do so. I have tried to use a next variable which has the value of the next line but it still doesn't add the String that i want.

```
String ex ="<Condition1>";
while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
if(next.trim().startsWith(ex))
                {
                    String b="\n"
                       +"<AdditionalECUVariables>"+
                        "var_3 \n"
                    +"var_4 \n"
                        +"var_5 \n"
                    +"var_6 \n";
                    bw.write(b);
                }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDYUH.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RNmP.png)

Comment: use `line` instead of `next`

Comment: the line is already used for reading from the file, next is another variable that i used to get the next line ,eg if line is at 140 next should be at 141

Comment: But you do not need `next`. if your line matches the condition write your new text before line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code looks mostly okay. I assume there's a line somewhere like `bw.write(line)`? If not, make sure to add one. E.g.:

```
String ex = "<Condition1>";
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // If this is the line we want to insert before...
    if (line.startsWith(ex)) {
        String b = "\n" +
                   "<AdditionalECUVariables>" +
                   "var_3\n" +
                   "var_4\n" +
                   "var_5\n" +
                   "var_6\n";
        // Write out our added data.
        bw.write(b);
    }
    // Always write out the line itself.
    bw.write(line);
}
```

**EDIT**

(Note that I have also used `line` instead of `next`, which I didn't see defined anywhere in your code.)

Comment: Yeah i did use it but the problem is that when i create a new file and check if the String was added or not before Condition1 it doesn't show up.

Comment: I don't understand what you wrote. Maybe you can give an example of the input file and the output from your code.

Comment: See also my edit. You need to use `line` instead of `next`.

Comment: i addded the 2 images,i already used the line in the while loop,the purpose of next is to get to the next line,in the images for example the String is added because the AdditionalECUVariables exists in the file already... my problem is when i don't have the AdditionECUVariables and i want to add it in the file before Condition1

Comment: I'm not sure how to help you at this point. I believe my code will work. Your code is unclear, since you haven't shared the other relevant parts of your code (like what `next` is). Also, your images make it look like maybe your code is already working, so at this point I'm not even sure what your question is.